# How do I interpolate a line number from __LINE__ into the name of a test in Perl?

Tags: perl, testing, interpolation, literals

When I try this test case:

```
$sel->is_text_present_ok("foo", ("$testname: line ", __LINE__));
```

I want to get this in the log:

```
ok 1 - is_text_present, "foo", Testcase-881: line 54
```

But I get chided on the command line:

> You named your test '54'.  You shouldn't use numbers for your test
>   names. Very confusing.

I figure I should be interpolating that literal into the string somehow, but I can't get to the bottom of it.  I've tried all sorts of configurations with the comma and quotation marks.

Is there any way to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: See also the `caller` function, if you'd like to have your testing framework always give the line number.

Comment: @derobert can you give an example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use the concatenation [operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators) `.` :

`$sel->is_text_present_ok("foo", "$testname: line " . __LINE__);`

Just FYI, you can interpolate it like this: `"$testname: line ${\(__LINE__)}"`

Comment: Man, I knew it would be obscenely simple.  Thanks so much!

Comment: ... but *don't" interpolate it like that

Comment: @Borodin Why not and what's a better alternative?

Comment: Because that syntax is explosion in ASCII factory and a likely candidate for a Critic policy. In my book, [`sprintf`](http://p3rl.org/sprintf) is better.