# individual test result to database

Tags: perl

I have lot's of *.t file each having number of test 
I am executing all the *.t file through Test::Harness.
How I can write the individual test status (Pass/Fail to a DB)

example

```
use Test::More ;
use strict;
ok( $foo eq $bar, "TestCase1 " ) ? &subUpdateResult(pass) : &subUpdateResult(Fail) ;
ok( $1 eq $2, 'test case 2' );
ok( $3 eq $4, 'test case 3' );
sub subUpdateResult
{
#now a only dummy code I will update this code to connect DB later
my $val=sfift;
print "val is $val\n";
}
done_testing();
```

but I am getting result like

```
ok 1 - TestCase1
ok 2
val is sfift
ok 3 - test case 2
ok 4 - test case 3
1..4
```

query:why I am getting the print result after  test case 2? and how to get the individual test status so that I can either update a database or write to an excel file

Comment: `sfift`? btw, this doesn't even compile under `strict` as you claim to be the case.

Comment: yes you are right I have manually written this code .if I use shift then still I am getting Error like ok 1
val is 1
ok 2 - 1
ok 3 - test case 2
ok 4 - test case 3
1..4
#     You named your test '1'.  You shouldn't use numbers for your test names.
#     Very confusing.

Comment: sfift is new in 5.20.0 :-)

Comment: Your code doesn't produce this output even after fixing it so it compiles (you didn't name any test '1'). You should really get your example working to demonstrate an actual problem before posting it.

Answer (score 1):

1. write `shift` not `sfift`.
2. The part which gives you error is

   ```
   sub ok {
   my($self, $test, $name) = @_;

   # $test might contain an object which we don't want to accidentally
   # store, so we turn it into a boolean.
   $test = $test ? 1 : 0;

   unless( $Have_Plan ) {
       require Carp;
       Carp::croak("You tried to run a test without a plan!  Gotta have a plan.");
   }

   lock $Curr_Test;
   $Curr_Test++;

   $self->diag(<<ERR) if defined $name and $name =~ /^[\d\s]+$/;
   You named your test '$name'.  You shouldn't use numbers for your test names.
   ```

This is where the error is coming from, `$name` argument can't be only numbers and whitespace. You need to correct line number 3 of your script, use the concatenation operator. (See: [How do I interpolate a line number from __LINE__ into the name of a test in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116954/how-do-i-interpolate-a-line-number-from-line-into-the-name-of-a-test-in-perl))

Your code doesn't even compile well, I think you are providing different data in order not to put your code in public. I modified it like below and it works. You'll have to do something similar. Also I don't know what `$1` and `$2` are here for?

```
      #!/usr/local/bin/perl
      use warnings;
      use Test::More ;
      use strict;
      my $foo = "something";
      my $bar = "something";
      ok( $foo eq $bar, "TestCase1 " ) ? &subUpdateResult('pass') : &subUpdateResult('fail') ;
      ok( $1 eq $2, 'test case 2' );
      ok( $3 eq $4, 'test case 3' );
      sub subUpdateResult
      {
      #now a only dummy code I will update this code to connect DB later
      my $val=shift;
      print "val is $val\n";
      }
      done_testing();
```

Comment: `$name argument can't contain number` - it can contain numbers. It can't be only numbers and whitespace.